# Xamarin - Include Windows in Platform-Specific Library NuGet Projects

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, nuget, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio for Mac (formerly called Xamarin Studio) has a cool feature where you can easily create [NuGet platform-specific multiplatform library projects](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/nuget-multiplatform-libraries/platform-specific/).

However, VSMac doesn't know how to include Windows as one of the target platforms (only iOS and Android).  I thought I would try creating a NuGet library project in VSMac (targeting only iOS and Android) and then have Visual Studio 2017 Windows add the Windows version, but VS2017Win can't even load the solution that VSMac creates ("This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects.").

Do I just have to sit tight and wait for Microsoft to add this functionality to VS2017Win?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I just have to sit tight and wait for Microsoft to add this functionality to VS2017Win?

If I understand your question correctly, you want to create a cross-platform package that uses native APIs on **iOS, Android, and Windows**. This functionality has been supported on **Visual Studio 2017** on windows. You can refer to the detail info from the document：[Create cross-platform packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/guides/create-cross-platform-packages)

Besides, since Visual Studio for Mac is still a preview version, many features need to be improved and added. If want to use Visual Studio for Mac to create the cross-platform package and include Windows as one of the target platforms, the current method seems to be only wait for Microsoft to add this functionality to VS2017 for Mac.

Hope this can help you.

Comment: By the way, the page you linked to only talks about Visual Studio 2015, but if you follow the instructions and ignore the warnings it works on VS 2017 too.